# Basic login using ExpressJS, MongoDB and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, mongodb, express

I'm trying to make a basic Express login when a user enters an existing username from MongoDB into a prompt:

HTML although not really relevant:

```
<a href="#home" class="login"><span class="fontawesome-circle"></span></a>
```

Main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.login').on('click', login);
});

function login(){
    var user = prompt('Username?', '');

    $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url: '/users/login',
            data: user
         }).done(function(response){
                console.log(response);
                window.location.replace('http://localhost:3030/');
            }).fail(function(response){
                console.log("Oops not working");
            });
}
```

App.js:

```
app.get('/users/login', function(req, res) {
    const data = req.body;
    if(db.users.find({username:data}) > 1){
        res.send("nice!");
    }else{
        res.send("not nice!");
    }
})
```

For now I'd just like to get Nice! when I type "admin" in the prompt, as there is a user is the users collection of "username":"admin" in MongoDB. Currently, I'm getting "Not Nice!" Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to do : db.users.find({username:data}).length > 1

Comment: that did it, thanks!

Comment: No worries. Also I would recommend using findOne instead of find and you can simply check if the returned object is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

hey you need to try something like this:
its my code used for my login modal

app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
const { username, pwd } = req.body;

```
const userModelInstance = UserModel.getInstance();

const users = await userModelInstance.retrieve({ userId: username });

if (users.length === 0) {
  return res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" });
}

const user = users[0];

console.log(users, user);

if (user.hashPassword !== pwd) {
  return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid password" });
}

return res.status(200).json(user);
```

});